# Form manipulation via VBS - need form to update after 1st selection

Tags: forms, vbscript, asp-classic, web-scraping, refresh

I created a script to BEGIN to do what I need.  This script interacts with the initial form.

I can fill out the form and submit, but it errors.

Upon further inspection, after a selection is made in the first dropdown field, the form is supposed to refresh with updated dropdown options.

With my code, it doesn't allow the form to refresh after the first selection is made.  Here is my somewhat-working code:

```
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ie.navigate "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/wl11.asp?Mode=1&SID=&brd=&typ="
ie.Visible = True
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop 

IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("Board").Value = "25"
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop 
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("County").Value = "11"
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("RecsPerPage").Value = "50"

For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If btn.type = "image" Then btn.Click()
Next
```

My question is - how do I allow the form to update after the first selection?  First selection being:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("Board").Value = "25"
```

I tried adding this after, but no dice:

```
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop
```

Comment: Does my question make sense?  I'm happy to clarify.  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web page by the link you gave contains `function DDChange()`, first and second form fields have `onchange` event linked to it. But for some reason this function is not called after the field is changed. So I've added to the script the same actions which the function does, and some extra loop to obtain complete document state. Here is the part of the code for form updating after first field is changed, it works ok for me:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/wl11.asp?Mode=1&SID=&brd=&typ="
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 10: Loop

IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("Board").Value = "25"
' see function DDChange() {} for details
Set Form = IE.Document.Forms("reportForm")
Form.hDDChange.Value = "Y"
Form.Submit

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 10: Loop
' additional loop to check doc state
Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
WScript.Echo IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("LicenseType").OuterHtml

' the rest part of your code here ...
```

BTW, there are two methods of data web-scraping: to interact with IE (you are implementing), or to get data via HTTP requests and parse it. First one is evident, but not reliable (you know, IE is heavy, slow, and sometimes user settings and old cookies affects workflow). Second one is more complex to setup, requires skills, but not need IE, so it is free of IE disadvantages.

Comment: Omega - I could hug you!  I must have gone to 100 links trying to find this answer.  You led me to (and understood) exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  I definitely get what you're saying about HTTP requests being the more optimal of the 2 options.  I'd say IE is my current skill level, but your posts are helping me learn what's possible with HTTPrequests.

Comment: I'm trying to use your method on the next page to click "next", but I must not be totally understanding your method.  Can you help me understand?  Seems like this should work.  CODE: Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
Set Form = IE.Document.Forms("reportForm")
Form.ChangePage(sAction).Value = "4"
Form.return(true).   Erroring on "Form.ChangePage" object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: I realize the "value" in ChangePage(sAction).Value = "4" isn't an option as was in your last example.  Tried Form.hPageAction.value = "4", but fail.  Thinking I need some combination of both...

Comment: Nevermind - got it working with this (not the sexiest way): For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If btn.name = "SearchForward" and btn.value = "Search" Then btn.Click()